# Why is Windows 7 slow resume from suspend?

Tags: windows-7, suspend

I have Windows 7 on an HP Mini 5101.  It is can be very slow to resume from suspend (not hibernate) state.   The time from power on to the login prompt varies from say 10 sec to over a minute.

This machine mainly gets used for sofa surfing so usually only Firefox and gtalk are running.

Any suggestions on how to achieve Mac-like start-up or suggestions on how to track down the problem appreciated.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? The time it takes to hibernate and to resume afterwards depends a lot on the amount of RAM you have. The more RAM, the longer it takes. Not sure why it would vary a lot though...

Comment: This may be related to your drive cache setting. Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/51813/hibernate-takes-4-minutes-38-seconds

Comment: @svish question is about about suspend, not hibernate - have udated the question to make it clearer

Comment: I have the same problem with my desktop - it sometimes takes 10min to resume!

Answer (score 1):

Run in command prompt

```
powercfg -energy
```

This will give a report on the energy state of your computer and highlight any potential problems.

More info: [howtogeek.com/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/)

Comment: that was a fun read, but didn't see anything that might be relevant to this problem. Thanks.